# get params with clean url in multi hosting environment

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, clean-urls

the website root contains three directories say `a,b,c` all acting as root for different domains

i created one `.htaccess` in directory `b` and added the following rules to it

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/$ /b/sample-page?bbi=$1&bbl=$2 [L]
```

In place of last line above, i have also tried

```
RewriteRule ^b/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /b/sample-page?bbi=$1&bbl=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Using above rules

`http://testsite.com/b/pageone.php` is successfully rewritten as

```
http://testsite.com/b/pageone
```

But `http://testsite.com/b/sample-page.php?bbi=value1&bbl=value2`

is rewritten as `http://testsite.com/b/sample-page?bbi=value1&bbl=value2` instead of

`http://testsite.com/b/sample-page/value1/value2`  or

```
http://testsite.com/sample-page/value1/value2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an `L` flag to your other rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

To handle the other situation, you'll need to add a rule **before** that one.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/b/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/b/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) $1.php?bbi=$2&bbl=$3 [L]
```

This should make it so when you go to `http://testsite.com/b/sample-page/value1/value2`, you get served the content at `/b/sample-page.php?bbi=value1&bbl=value2`

Comment: @RishiKalia Sorry, tested it on my own apache install, needed the 2 `/b` in the last 2 conditions